# Convert an alphanumeric string into an array of numbers in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to convert a cell in VBA which is like this:

> I am 99 years old and I was born in 1918.

Into an array that would contain and display on the cell as:

> [99,1918]

Here is my code:

```
Sub ConvertColumnToArray(Length As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer, infoArray As Variant
    Set Column = Sheets("Short Desc")
    For i = 2 To Length
        infoArray = StringToIntArray(Column.Range("A" & i))
        Column.Range("A" & i) = "[" & infoArray(0) & "," & infoArray(1) & "]"
    End For
End Sub

Function StringToIntArray(str As String) As Variant
    'the code to add
End Function
```

Comment: You can try using regular expressions, based on the numbers 0-9 and a space (in order to distinguish different numbers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Function StringToIntArray(str As String) As Variant
  Static regex As Object 'VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp

  If regex Is Nothing Then
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")  ' New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    regex.Global = True
    regex.Pattern = "\d+"
  End If

  Dim matches As Object ' MatchCollection
  Set matches = regex.Execute(str)

  If matches.Count > 0 Then
    Dim result() As Long
    ReDim result(0 To matches.Count - 1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
      result(i) = CLng(matches(i).Value)
    Next

    StringToIntArray = result
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

If you decide to avoid using `RegEx`, this is a faster, working solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim stringInput As String
    stringInput = "I am 99 years old and I was born in 1918"
    Debug.Print Join(StringToIntArray(stringInput), " ")

End Sub

Function StringToIntArray(myInput As String) As Variant

    Dim i As Long
    Dim infoArray As Variant
    Dim unitArray As Variant
    Dim result As Variant

    infoArray = Split(myInput)

    For Each unitArray In infoArray
        If IsNumeric(unitArray) Then
            result = result & " " & unitArray
        End If
    Next
    StringToIntArray = Split(Trim(result))

End Function
```

- It splits the string by spaces to an array - `infoArray`.
- For each unit, if the unit is numeric it adds it to a string `result`.
- The string `result` is parsed to a `StringToIntArray` through `Split()` operation.

As probably noted, if there is a `.` at the end of the `stringInput`, like this "... in 1918.", the year "1918" would not be taken into account, because it is "1918." and it is not a numeric. Thus, additional "strip" has to be carried out, stripping the dots.

Comment: Same kind stripping has to be done for e.g. commas after numbers inside the string. `I am 99, you know.`

Comment: @GSerg - yes, the quick performance comes with a price. For no strip the RegEx is probably the best option. Or loop through every character.

Comment: Well, running your function (just `StringToIntArray`, without the outer `Join`) 100000 times takes 628ms on machine, and running my function 100000 times takes 609ms...

Comment: @GSerg - this is because of the string concatenation within the function, it is an extremely slow process. In the general case, I would have added to a list, but it was too much information in the answer. If you want to test again, remove this line `result = result & " " & unitArray` and see the difference.

Comment: Friendly hint: suggest to return `StringToIntArray = Split(Trim(result))` otherwise you get an empty array item first :-)

Answer (score 4):

Just for kicks, if you have Excel 2016 with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you could use this **array** formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(--(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),""))
```

where

```
seq_99 refers to:  =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

Or, to show the brackets as I see you did in your code:

```
=CONCAT("[",TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IFERROR(--(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1)," ",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),"")),"]")
```

If I were going to use VBA, I'd use something like:

```
Function StringToIntArray(str As String) As String
    Dim v, w, s As String

v = Split(str)
For Each w In v
    If IsNumeric(w) Then
        s = s & "," & w
    End If
Next w

StringToIntArray = "[" & Mid(s, 2) & "]"

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider:

```
Public Function StringToIntArray(str As String) As Variant
    Dim temp As String, i As Long, L As Long
    Dim CH As String
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    temp = ""
    L = Len(str)
    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(str, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
            temp = temp & CH
        Else
            temp = temp & " "
        End If
    Next i

    StringToIntArray = Split(wf.Trim(temp), " ")

End Function
```

For example:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim s As String, arr, a, output As String
    s = "qwerty45bgt567cdrew098"

    arr = StringToIntArray(s)
    output = ""

    For Each a In arr
        output = output & a & vbCrLf
    Next a
    MsgBox output

End Sub
```

[image]

The code does not rely on on the [*space*] character.  It will return an array of all numeric sub-strings of an input string.